# Delete Dataframe indices in each loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe through which I want to loop and execute a statement based on a condition on indices. I want the dataframe to be updated with each loop such that the indices that were processed in the previous loop are deleted from the dataframe so that in each next loop, there should be less rows for iteration.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000,5)), columns['a','b','c','d','e'])

for index,b,c in zip(df.index, df.b, df.c):
    if index%2==0:
        pass
df = df.drop(df.index[index])
```

I want to update the dataframe in this last step. The indices for which **if index%2==0:** is True, should be removed from the dataframe so that in the next iteration, the length of datframe be reduced to half(in this case).
      It is giving me the error for the bounds of indices which is obvious as the dataframe is not properly updated. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should complete your if...else logic

```
l=[]
for index,b,c in zip(df.index, df.b, df.c):
    if index%2==0:
        pass
    else : 
        l.append(index)
df=df.drop(l)    
df.shape
Out[214]: (500, 5)
```

Comment: @cs95 yep , need a cup of coffee.

Comment: It is better now!

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve. Let us say the dataframe have 1000 rows. In first iteration it will go through all 1000 of them and let it collect 121 random indices meeting a specific condition. Now I want that when the next iteration follows, there should be (1000 - 121) rows to iterate over. Similarly, let in this next iteration, 53 indices meet a condition. Then these 53 indices should be deleted so in the next loop, only (1000-121-53) rows are there to carry out iteration. **The number of rows should decrease with each loop** (PS: I don't drink coffee @cs95  :-D)